# Play Framework's JavaForms

Tags: web, playframework

So in JavaForms section of Play 2.1.1 documentation, there is a line of code:

```
Form<User> userForm = form(User.class);
```

Where does this "form(User.class)" function come from?

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaForms

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form(...)` is a static method of the `play.data.Form` class.

If you import `play.data.Form`, you can use `Form.form(User.class)` or you can do a static import to use only the `form(User.class)` syntax : `import static play.data.Form.form;`